# What's the meaning of "drapish"?

Tags: word-meaning, poetry

What's the meaning of "drapish"?
I saw this word in the [poem "The Buddha" by Jack Kerouac](http://www.blogcitylights.com/2015/03/30/the-city-lights-books-of-jack-kerouac/).
However,I can't find the meaning on the internet.

> I used to sit under trees and meditate
>   on the diamond bright silence of darkness
>   and the bright look of diamonds in space
>   and space that was stiff with lights
>   and diamonds shot through, and silence
>
> And when a dog barked I took it for soundwaves
>   and cars passing too, and once I heard
>   a jet-plane which I thought was a mosquito
>   in my heart, and once I saw salmon walls
>   of pink and roses, moving and ululating
>   **with the drapish**
>
> Once I forgave dogs, and pitied men, sat
>   in the rain countin’ Juju beads, raindrops
>   are ecstasy, ecstasy is raindrops – birds
>   sleep when the trees are giving out light
>   in the night, rabbits sleep too, and dogs
>
> I had a path that I followed thru piney woods
>   and a phosphorescent white hound-dog named Bob
>   who led me the way when the clouds covered
>   the stars, and then communicated to me
>   the sleepings of a loving dog enamoured
>
> of God

Comment: Could it be the name of a person or an object? Maybe in some local dialect or language, other than English?

Comment: @Varun KN I don't really know,maybe your point is in accord with the fact. I will add the content at the end as specific detail

Comment: @Hugo *drapish* is not a real word.  The closest match to it is "drape" meaning "to hang from/over like cloth" or "drapes" meaning something like "curtains".  "Drapish" sounds like an adjective meaning "like drapes" but here it's not modifying anything.  Therefore it's a made up word and we all have to guess what Kerouac meant by it, or it's a word for something in another language.

Comment: [This site](https://www.nameslook.com/drapish/) claims it means ***Inspiring, Master of their own destiny, Intuitive***. But since Kerouac seems to be the only writer who's ever used it (apart from a few cases where people have whimsically used it to mean ***like drapes, loosely hanging***), I think we can reasonably say it means ***whatever you want it to mean***. It's not something ELL should be pronouncing on - effectively it's Lit Crit / poetic interpretation.

Comment: That's quite a surprising.I would have thought it's just an uncommon word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think that's a site for baby names.  Drapish is a possible last name (also Drapisz and Drapisch, depending on the country) ... although I wouldn't be surprised if the baby-name site just makes up their own pleasant-sounding "meaning" when they can't find anything easily.

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes. The OP tried to look the word up. The answer might be, "We don't know what Kerouac means; it's not a real word," but I'm not sure that necessitates closing the question. (It *would* be Lit Crit had the question asked, "I know this isn't a real word – so what does Kerouac mean?" – but it doesn't.)

Comment: @J.R.  but then wouldn't that make it entirely based on opinion, since there is no way to objectively verify its meaning?  Honestly, I have no idea what he means -- there's not enough information in the context of the poem for me to even *guess*.  In a Lit Crit class I'd point it out as an example of *obscure writing*, ignore it, and move on to the comprehensible parts of the poem.

Comment: @Andrew - If a learner can't find an unusual word in the dictionary, they don't really have any way to tell if it's a faux word coined by a poet, or a word that's fairly well understood by a segment of native speakers but simply not in the dictionary for some reason. I think learners should feel welcome to ask about such words here, where they might receive helpful, instructive guidance as opposed to closevotes coupled with admonishing comments. (By the way, I thought your initial comment was helpful, and, had it been an answer, I probably would have upvoted it as such.)

Comment: This is a legitimate question, which does not have a definition as an answer.  Some combination of Andrew and or Fumblefinger's comments make for a decent good-as-it-can-be answer.

Comment: Many newly formed words have all the traits you'd expect a word to have: morphology, pronunciation, meaning, sometimes even spelling.  Others do not, and their meaning or status as words is less clear.  But whatever the answer is – perhaps that it's a new word formed by an established process with a meaning native speakers are likely to be able to guess, or perhaps that it's a new word whose derivation and meaning are unclear – in my opinion *that should be an answer*, not a close reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Drapish" is a word that Kerouac used to try to describe something he imagined while he was meditating.

I've found two types of usages for "drapish" when I searched. The first is a surname and the second describes clothing that "[drapes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drape)." In this context "drapes" means "hangs or rests limply" or "falls or hangs in loose folds". A related word (for me) is "drapey", for example

[image: three tops that have loose folds of fabric]

The phrase "moving and ululating" makes me think that "drapish" is trying to describe a feeling of something hanging loosely and maybe moving back and forth, but there's no way to say for certain. Kerouac probably purposefully chose to create a word because there wasn't one in common usage that meant exactly what he wanted to express.